# Scan Specific Rectangle of Interest

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, cgrect

I am trying to scan a rectangle of interest in my AVCaptureSession. I am using the below.

```
metadataObject.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.4, width: 1, height: 0.2)
```

My assumption is this will give me a section in the center of the screen that if any barcode intersects it will be scanned. However, this is not working. Nothing is scanned. If I use this

```
metadataObject.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
```

things scan just fine, so I know the rectOfInterest is causing the things not to scan. Am I approaching the rectOfInterest incorrectly? I assume it is a rect based on percentage of the preview view.

Comment: did you found anything ?